# How to add an icon to System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem?

Tags: .net, winforms, menu, contextmenu

I tried to add an icon to one of my context menu items, but I couldn't do it. Can anybody help me?

Here's the code I've written:

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu notifyContextMenu;
 private void foo() {
            if (notifyIcon == null) {
                notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();   
            }

           if (notifyContextMenu == null) {
               notifyContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
               notifyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit");
               // How do I add an icon to this context menu item?
             }
            notifyIcon.ContextMenu =  notifyContextMenu;
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MainMenu/ContextMenu are obsolete, you should use the menu strip classes instead.

Change

```
notifyContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
notifyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit");
```

to

```
notifyContextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
var exitMenuItem = notifyContextMenu.Items.Add("Exit");
exitMenuItem.Image = ...;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.image.aspx

Finally attach the context menu strip to notify icon,

```
notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = notifyContextMenu;
```

Comment: Well, that's not really true. Yes, the `...Strip` classes are newer, but they'll produce menus that *look* utterly abhorrent on Windows Vista and later. Instead of asking Windows to draw the menus, they're all custom drawn with .NET code. They look good in Windows XP and they match the custom drawn menus used in Office XP, but technology has moved a long way since then. Using these ugly menus in an attempt to stave off obsolescence seems like a pretty foolish decision to me. Your app will never look right on modern versions of Windows.

Comment: Though the native wrapper does have better look on Windows Vista and above, the same effect can be achieved in strip classes via custom renderer,  http://code.google.com/p/szotar/source/browse/trunk/Client/Szotar.WindowsForms/Base/NativeToolStripRenderer.cs

Comment: Not even close to the same... (I've tried it, re-written it, tweaked it, tried some more. Not the same. Worse, no matter how much you make it *look* like the native menus, it won't *behave* like the native menus.) But indeed, better...

Answer (score 14):

[Lex Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671895/366904) covers the *simplest* way to do this: switch from the `MainMenu` control to the `MenuStrip` control, which provides built-in, out-of-the-box support for adding icons to each menu item. Unfortunately, as I discussed in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671585/system-windows-forms-menuitem-how-to-add-an-icon#comment13845835_10671895) to his answer, this solution has some ugly consequences.

In particular, if you use the `MenuStrip` control, your menus will forever look ugly and out of place on newer versions of Windows because they're custom drawn by .NET code that will probably never be updated. Sure, they look slick on Windows XP, but that's been old news for at least 5 years. Menus look totally different starting with Windows Vista, and that's what your user will expect from your app, too. The coolest icons in the world just won't help you look any more modern. Compare:

[image: MenuStrip (and its little brother, ContextMenuStrip) look downright ugly on Windows Vista and later, compared to the platform native menus, as implemented with MainMenu (and its little brother, ContextMenu)]

So the somewhat more involved solution is to stick with the `MainMenu` control, which actually uses menus drawn by Windows itself, but write some code that handles adding an icon.

And fortunately, Wyatt O'Day has already written a great custom control that does this for you. All you have to do is download it, drop it into your project, compile, and start using it. It's open-source, licensed under the BSD license, and it produces menus that look *platform native on all versions of Windows*. Download it [here from his website](http://wyday.com/vistamenu/), or start with [his introduction and 100% accurate rant](http://wyday.com/blog/2009/making-the-menus-in-your-net-app-look-professional/).

The results are **awesome**:

[image: Comparing the appearance of Wyatt's VistaMenu control on 4 different operating systems: Windows 7, Vista, XP, and 2000. On all 4, it looks just like the platform native menus, except with icons!]

Comment: Reuse something like VistaMenu is a better option. I agree.

Comment: @Cody Gray, in fact I woudn't like to use some third-party library only for the context menu. I want to solve this issue by my own. But how? It would be great if my context menu looks like Vista menu and has menuItems with images. What should I do?

Comment: @Alex: The library I linked to is open source, which means you can look at the code, see what it does, and use it as an example to write your own code.

Comment: "The results are awesome" is relative because the MainMenu and ContextMenu look ugly compared with their equivalent in UWP apps. And worse, customize the native menus requires to add a third-party library or write a lot of extra code that's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function SetMenuItemInfo to add icon to menu items.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.Popup += MenuItem_Popup;
            SetMenuInfo(menu.Handle, new MENUINFO());
            var item = menu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", (sender, e) => Application.Exit());
            SetImage(item, Properties.Resources.Image1);

            var notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon
            {
                Icon = Properties.Resources.Icon1,
                ContextMenu = menu
            };
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            Application.Run();
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }

        static Dictionary<MenuItem, IntPtr> MenuBitmaps = new Dictionary<MenuItem, IntPtr>();

        static void SetImage(MenuItem item, Image img)
        {
            using (var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
            {
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
                MenuBitmaps[item] = bmp.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            }
        }

        static void MenuItem_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var info = new MENUITEMINFO();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (MenuItem item in ((Menu)sender).MenuItems)
                if (item.Visible)
                {
                    if (MenuBitmaps.TryGetValue(item, out info.hbmpItem))
                        SetMenuItemInfo(((Menu)sender).Handle, i, true, info);
                    i++;
                }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool SetMenuInfo(IntPtr hMenu, MENUINFO lpcmi);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool SetMenuItemInfo(IntPtr hMenu, int uItem, bool fByPosition, MENUITEMINFO lpmii);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public class MENUINFO
    {
        public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUINFO));
        public int fMask = 0x10; //MIM_STYLE
        public int dwStyle = 0x4000000; //MNS_CHECKORBMP
        public uint cyMax;
        public IntPtr hbrBack;
        public int dwContextHelpID;
        public IntPtr dwMenuData;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public class MENUITEMINFO
    {
        public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));
        public int fMask = 0x80; //MIIM_BITMAP
        public int fType;
        public int fState;
        public int wID;
        public IntPtr hSubMenu;
        public IntPtr hbmpChecked;
        public IntPtr hbmpUnchecked;
        public IntPtr dwItemData;
        public IntPtr dwTypeData;
        public int cch;
        public IntPtr hbmpItem;
    }
}
```