# Context menu must be clicked twice

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, richtextbox, right-click

I have added a context menu to a RichTextBox, however the user has to right-click twice for it to appear. What have I missed?

```
Private Sub rtf_Notes_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles rtf_Notes.MouseUp

    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
        Dim contextMenu As ContextMenu = New System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu()
        Dim menuItem_Font As New MenuItem("Selection Font...")
        AddHandler menuItem_Font.Click, AddressOf RightClick_Font
        Dim menuItem_Cut As New MenuItem("Cut")
        AddHandler menuItem_Cut.Click, AddressOf RightClick_Cut
        Dim menuItem_Copy As New MenuItem("Copy")
        AddHandler menuItem_Copy.Click, AddressOf RightClick_Copy
        Dim menuItem_Paste As New MenuItem("Paste")
        AddHandler menuItem_Paste.Click, AddressOf RightClick_Paste
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem_Font)
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add("-")
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem_Cut)
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem_Copy)
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuItem_Paste)
        rtf_Notes.ContextMenu = contextMenu
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are assigning the context menu to `rtf_Notes.ContextMenu` but you aren't actually showing it. On the second click the menu has been constructed and assigned to the text fields, and the built in behaviour for the `ContextMenu` property will kick in and display your constructed context menu

Comment: Like Pro Grammer says. All of this initialization should be done in the Load event, then you don't need to handle MouseUp at all.

Comment: Thanks! That took care of it. How do you add icons to the context menu?

Comment: The way we generally do things here is, when you have a follow-up question, you ask a new question. In this case, adding icons to a context menu is not as simple as it sounds. The ContextMenu control doesn't have this functionality built in. At some point, WinForms introduced the ContextMenuStrip control that has built-in support for icons, but it has other problems, namely that it's ugly and non-native looking, so you probably don't want to use it. You can get icons on the ContextMenu control, but it's a fair amount of work. Or you can grab a library that has already done the work for you.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10672152/366904

Comment: Thanks Cody for setting me straight, and I found and switched to the ContextmenuStrip last night, worked great.